# How to match another object's rotation delta?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I'm trying to have one object match another object's rotation delta. So if object A rotates 90 degrees around Y axis I want object B to also rotate 90 degrees around Y axis. Since I want to do it every frame, I save the initial rotations of both objects. I tried doing it like this, based on this [forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/get-the-difference-between-two-quaternions-and-add-it-to-another-quaternion.513187/):

```
objectB.transform.localRotation = (initialObjectARotation * Quaternion.Inverse(objectA.transform.localRotation)) * initialObjectBRotation;
```

The issue is that now the rotation is inversed (I'm not sure this is the correct term, but if I rotate `objectA` right then `objectB` rotates left etc.). How can I fix this?

Comment: Do they have the same parent object? Or why do you use the local rotation?

Comment: I'm using `localRotation` because I want this to be independent of parent's rotation.

Comment: But then `localRotation` (=relative to the parent) is exactly **not** what you want to use but rather the global absolute `rotation` ...

Comment: Yes you are right, what I meant to say is that I want it to work relative to the parent. This is not the main issue here as both game objects have no parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the absolute rotation of B (the subject doing the matching) and A (the target being matched) from the previous frame and the new absolute rotation of A, you can solve for the new absolute rotation of B interpreting the A difference along the **local axes** of each object:

```
Quaternion oldB; // previous global rotation of subject
Quaternion oldA; // previous global rotation of target
Quaternion newA = transformA.rotation; // current global rotation of target

// solve for new global rotation of subject
Quaternion newB = oldB * Quaternion.Inverse(oldA) * newA;
```

---

If that gives you results you don't like you could try interpreting the diff along **global axes**:

```
// solve for new global rotation of subject
Quaternion newB = newA * Quaternion.Inverse(oldA) * oldB;
```

---

Finally, if you really want it relative to the **axes of each object's parent**, it's a bit more complicated because it involves the previous parent rotations (absolute), the previous local rotations of the objects, and the current absolute rotation of A to give you the current absolute of B. :

```
Quaternion oldBParent; // previous global rotation of subject's parent
Quaternion oldBLocal; // previous local rotation of subject
Quaternion oldAParent; // previous global rotation of target's parent
Quaternion oldALocal; // previous local rotation of target

// solve for new global rotation of subject
Quaternion newB = oldBParent * Quaternion.Inverse(oldAParent) * newA 
        * Quaternion.Inverse(oldALocal) * oldBLocal;
```

Note that if there is no parent, then the parent rotations are `Quaternion.identity` and it is equivalent to the **global axes** form. Neat!

---

And of course once you have `newB`, you only need to apply the new rotation with `transformB.rotation = newB;`.

Comment: Thanks for the little refreshing course ;) Finally we have them all together in a single place ^^